# return mutliple variables from a function to be used elsewhere in Python program

Tags: python-3.x, function, return-value

I am trying to extract a specific variable from a `def` in Python.  The `def` has the format as follows:

```
def print_prediction(file_name):
    prediction_feature = extract_features(file_name)
    prediction_feature = prediction_feature.reshape(1, num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)
    model_path = os.path.join("ModelPath")
    model = load_model(filepath)

    predicted_vector = np.argmax(model.predict(prediction_feature), axis=-1)
    predicted_class = le.inverse_transform(predicted_vector)
    print("The predicted class is:", predicted_class[0])

    predicted_proba_vector = model.predict(prediction_feature)
    predicted_proba = predicted_proba_vector[0]
    for i in range(len(predicted_proba)):
        category = le.inverse_transform(np.array([i]))
        print(category[0], "\t\t : ", format(predicted_proba[i], '.15f'))
    print('\n')

    return (predicted_proba_vector, category)
```

The skeleton of the overall code is as follows:

```
imports

def

for index, row in metadata.iterrows():
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(fulldatasetpath)+'/'+str(row["file_name"]))
    print_prediction(file_path)
    prob1 = predicted_proba_vector[0]
    cat1 = format(predicted_proba[1], '.15f'

    predictions.append([file_path, prob1])
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Can you tell me how I can go about getting the `return` values from the `def`.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the return value of a function?

Comment: First of all, a function, not a def. But what do you mean? To get values from the function you need to run it and assign the result to a variable/variables.

Comment: @Brian yes, from the `def`

Comment: `predicted_proba_vector, category = print_prediction(file_name)` something like that would assign values to variables

Comment: @RolvApneseth, in the "skeleton" code that I provided, the 3rd line in the for loop, I should use `predicted_proba_vector, category = print_prediction(file_name)`?

Comment: Yes Joe, assuming you want the variable names the same after it exits the function, that is correct (Except 'file_name', should be 'file_path' in your case)

Comment: Yes just change `file_name` to your variable `file_path`.

Comment: @RolvApneseth, thanks for your help!  Can you post that as a solution so that I can accept it on this forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the return values from `print_prediction` to variables just change the 2nd line inside your `for` loop to:

```
predicted_proba_vector, category = print_prediction(file_path)
```

---

The full loop should then look like:

```
for index, row in metadata.iterrows():
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(fulldatasetpath)+'/'+str(row["file_name"]))
    predicted_proba_vector, category = print_prediction(file_path)
    prob1 = predicted_proba_vector[0]
    cat1 = format(predicted_proba[1], '.15f')

    predictions.append([file_path, prob1])
    time.sleep(.1)
```